# Getting error 3121 while trying to integrate Sage Pay in our website

Tags: php, opayo

I am working on an e-commerce site, and I have to integrate Sage Pay payment gateway. Everything is working fine except getting the following error when trying to checkout.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
    $serverLive="https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp";
$YOUR_VENDOR_LOGIN_NAME = "alpinetravelint";
$PAYMENT_CRYPT="VendorTxCode=406227821909&Amount=320.00&Currency=GBP&Description=1ACMEWidget&SuccessURL=http://salentro.com/core/snowtrax/index.php&FailureURL=http://salentro.com/core/snowtrax/login.php&BillingSurname=Smith&BillingFirstnames=John&BillingAddress1=123 Main Street&BillingCity=Anywhere&BillingPostCode=W1A 1BL&BillingCountry=GB&DeliverySurname=Smith&DeliveryFirstnames=test&DeliverAddress1=123Main Street&DeliveryCity=Anywhere&DeliveryPostCode=W1A 1BL&DeliveryCountry=GB";
function pkcs5_pad($text, $blocksize)
{
    $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
    return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}

function encryptFieldData($input)
{
    $key = "4bBtA2UYvZKry3tb";
    $iv = $key;

    $cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, "", MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, "");
    if (mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, $key, $iv) != -1)
    {
        $cipherText = mcrypt_generic($cipher,$input );
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);

        $enc = bin2hex($cipherText);
    }
    return $enc;
}

$str = $PAYMENT_CRYPT;
$datapadded = pkcs5_pad($str,16);
$cryptpadded = "@" . encryptFieldData($datapadded);

?>
<form action="<?php echo $serverLive ;?>" method="POST" id="SagePayForm" name="SagePayForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="VPSProtocol" value="2.23" />
    <input type="hidden" name="TxType" value="PAYMENT" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Vendor" value="<?php echo $YOUR_VENDOR_LOGIN_NAME ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Crypt" value="<?php echo $cryptpadded ?>">    
    <input type="image" src="images/buynow-sagepay.png" />
</form>
```

Now, the problem is when I try to run this code, I got following error code:

> 3121 : The DeliveryFirstnames value is too long.

How can I sort out this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error is being generated because you are sending

```
DeliveryFirstnames=test&DeliverAddress1=123Main Street
```

Because the DeliveryAddress is incorrectly spelt, the DeliveryFirstNames is picking up the first name as `test&DeliverAddress1=123Main Street` rather than `test`

Change the above to

```
DeliveryFirstnames=test&DeliveryAddress1=123Main Street
```